# Recover php mysql query with ajax/json?

Tags: php, jquery, json

How to recover data from research by json? I would like to recover the separate items as the result show in php page to create new elements, for example recover item.f, item.m to create new elements like  item.f < / div> < span > item.m. .. thank you

(error presented at)
Error Can not read property of items " of null

Php page ( does the query )

```
if ($_GET['action'] == "chatheartbeat") { chatHeartbeat(); }

function chatHeartbeat() {
    $sql = "select * from mensagens ";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    $items = '';
    $chatBoxes = array();
    while ($chat = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $items. = << < EOD
{ 
"s": "0", 
"f": "{$chat['de']}", 
"m": "{$chat['mensagem']}", 
"i": "{$chat['img']}" 
}, 
EOD;
    }
}
```

Index ( calls the pair query present the results - error here -  need help here)

```
$.ajax({
    url: "asd.php?action=chatheartbeat",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
            alert(item.f)
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Don't generate json manually, generate an array / object and use `json_encode()` to generate valid json.

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Answer (score 1):

As @jeroen says dont manually generate JSON Strings use `json_encode()` to create a JSONString from a PHP array or an object.

```
if ($_GET['action'] == "chatheartbeat") {
    $sql = "select * from mensagens "; 
    $query = mysql_query($sql); 

    $chatBoxes = array(); 

    while ($chat = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { 
        $t - new stdClass();
        $t->s   = "0";
        $t->f   = $chat['de'];
        $t->m   = $chat['mensagem'];
        $t->i   = $chat['img'];

        $chatBoxes[] = $t;
    }

    $items = json_encode($chatBoxes);

    // now just echo $items to return it to the javascript in the browser
    // here or later in the code if there is more to your code than you showed us
    echo $items;            
}
```

> References:
>
> [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)
>
> [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: And then you'd need to output it as well :-) I don't understand how the OP got into the `success` function anyway with invalid json (nothing) so there is probably something else going on too...

Comment: yea I was not to sure what they were going to do with it once they created it. I was hoping they alreday had that covered!

Comment: Not sure why the code was in a function, I removed it as it seemed irrelevant at least to the purposes of this answer

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the help, I managed to solve the problem as follows

Php page ( does the query )

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mensagens");         
while( $array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$table[]= array("de"=>$array['de'],"mensagem"=>$array['mensagem']); }                         
echo json_encode($table);
```

Index

```
  $.ajax({                                      
  url: 'asd.php',                                                    
  dataType: 'json',               
  success: function(data)          
  {
   for($i=0; $i < data.length; $i++){
$("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle+" .chatboxcontent").append(
'<div class="message"><span class="from">'+data[$i].de+':&nbsp;&nbsp;
</span><span class=content">'+data[$i].mensagem+'</span></div>');
}}
});
```